# Please help me with the Collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know why the class "collapse in" doesn't work. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<h4> <a href="#col1Content" data-toggle="collapse">Column1</a>
</h4>
<div id="col1Content" class="collapse in">
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla 
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code does work: http://www.codeply.com/go/BDooXshc59 what version of Bootstrap are you trying to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "doesn't work" you should write what you expect and what exactly is the problem.

Here is your code with all the relevant libraries:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<h4> <a href="#col1Content" data-toggle="collapse">Column1</a>
</h4>
<div id="col1Content" class="collapse in">
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla 
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 
 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
</div>
</div>
```

Everything there works as expected.
If you want the text block to be hidden you should remove the `in` from the class list.

Comment: thanks for the help, it was problem with one of the script. Cheers

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help :)